# Pure Java Multi-part/Form-Data Parser

Tags: java, parsing

I need a http based multi-part/form-data parser written in pure java (no servlets).  I need to read the file uploaded via post. I have a custom , minimal web server and it won't have servlet support. So basically all I need is a class/code that reads the multi-part/form-data post , and reads out the uploaded file.  Can anyone post me a link to such a code?

**UPDATE**

Found Apache FileUpload component.

Comment: What it mean "no servlets"? Are you running in container or you want to create your own HTTP server?

Comment: dont you use a servlet where you handle a POST request?

Comment: I have my own custom (minimal) web server written in java. I need to read files posted.

Comment: I updated my question, please see above.

Comment: So.. You need a `multipart/form-data` parser API without any `javax.servlet` dependencies? You just feed an `InputStream` representing the request body to it and then get `List<Part>` or something. Right?